# How to check if user is authorized or guest

Tags: laravel

I need a piece of advice on how to check whether the user authorized or guest. Maybe you'll give me a hint and recommend where to look. Should I use sockets for this? I really don't know where to start from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where your code is at, you can either pass the `auth` middleware to the route or controller's constructor
And to manually check, the syntax is semantic and expected

Using the helper function

```php
auth()->check();
```

Using the Auth facade

```php
Auth::check();
```

Both will return `true` if the user is authenticated and `false` if the user is a guest

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

**Determining If The Current User Is Authenticated**

To determine if the user is already logged into your application, you may use the `check` method on the `Auth` facade, which will return `true` if the user is authenticated:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```